# Got an error Django internal server error

Tags: python, django, server

Got this error while trying to create a view on Django: 
 raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '' does not appear to h
ave any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

Tried many solutions online both on deleting one of the url.py folders but none worked out

Answer (score 0):

Later got a work over to the question
my urlpatterns was written in camel case urlPatterns so i have to correct it and it work perfectly